# Laminate floor against fireplace brick

Tags: fireplace, brick, laminate-floor

We are installing a laminate floor in our family room and have precisely the same problem as described in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24615/how-do-i-cut-a-brick-fireplace-hearth-to-allow-for-a-laminate-flooring-expansion).  The brick is not even close to flat where it meets the floor, leading to ugly gaps.

The solutions given in the linked question are not what we'd like to have.  No trim or border.  We'd really much rather have the "floor underneath" look, where the floor appears to simply disappear underneath everything in the room, including the fireplace brick.

This implies that we have to cut the brick somehow.  I've seen a few online videos showing how to do this, but they were lucky enough to have a grout line at floor level.  There is no grout line at the correct level - the floor goes right into the physical brick.

I am looking for methods and suggestions regarding how to best cut the brick.  Tools, gotchas, ways to make sure it looks neat, etc.  I only get one shot at getting this right.  :)

As an alternative, I'd consider using some kind of a "gap filler" to hide the gap, as long as it is level with the floor and can be colored to match either the grout or the floor.

Comment: I think you should consider cutting the flooring so it fits the irregular brick wall tightly. This can be done various ways, but I have seen it look really good when done well.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it:  I see two problems with that:  1)  It will require endless measuring, re-measuring, and fiddling.  2)  There will be no expansion gap.

Comment: You don't do it by measuring, you use dividers or a compass to transfer contours and shapes. I admit I didn't consider expansion though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rent an "undercut saw" and put a diamond blade in it. Cut a channel along the floor at a suitable height. Brick cuts fairly easily and you'll have a dead-straight, perfect fit to your floor. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV2G7gJh2es)

You'll have to do a little creative grinding with other tools near the wall where the circular saw won't reach. You can get diamond-grit blades for reciprocating saws, or maybe go at it with some patience and a rotary tool with grinding bit.

This work is very dusty. Use a vacuum held by a helper and seal off the room.

Comment: You may consider picking up an "oscillating cutter" or "flush cutter" tool and finding an abrasive blade for it. They're quite handy for these types of cuts. I would use it _only_ for the finishing bits where your "undercut saw" won't reach, as the blades are usually pretty small and it would be _painfully_ slow to do the whole thing with this. They're quite handy for other DIY projects, as well (I keep wondering how I ever survived 28 years of home ownership without one).

Comment: @FreeMan:  yes, I have one of those tools (I've gone through several by now, actually).  I wouldn't want to do the entire cut with that!  but you are right, it would be great for fiddling with a few places if I need to.