# How to place engineered hardwood against rough fireplace hearth?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, rock, hearth

We are going to replace the carpet in our living room with engineered hardwood flooring. We’ve installed the flooring elsewhere in our home so that part isn’t a problem.

The problem is what do we do against the rock hearth?

Everywhere else we’ve installed flooring there is baseboard or hardwood quarter round (*kitchen*).

Can’t do baseboard around the hearth. Does quarter round that matches the floor work?

[image: Rock Hearth]

Comment: Quarter round is the easy choice but may not look right at the grout lines (gaps) unless the gaps are filled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laminate floor against fireplace brick](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198459/laminate-floor-against-fireplace-brick) My answer here is the same as there... nothing will look professional against the stone. You must go under it.

Comment: @isherwood I may be able to go under it once the carpet is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transition "tee" molding used for setting between 2 different runs of floor. One edge can be shaped to conform to the stone, it will match the color of the floor you choose and will give the required movement the flooring needs. It will look, in my opinion, less conspicuous once in place. That is if it is a floating installation. If it is a glue or nail down, scribe to fit it tight, that's all you will need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want some form/color of bullnose trim near your fireplace.   You just install it butt against hearth (as good as you can while maintaining proper install angles).   Then just slide engineered wood in - while leaving room for expansion.   You can add caulking to the other side to hide "gaps" after you are done.   You can find bullnose trim in a variety of colors and even wood (wouldn't be my first choice here).

[image]

Comment: Does the rounded edge go against the hearth or against the flooring?